# Angular validate only when input has data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular 1.4 with ng-pattern and a custom async validator.

I have 2 fields with validation, one is required and the other is not. I need to validate the second filed WHEN it DOES have something in it. Issue is that I cannot submit the form when the second field's validators do not pass.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Thanks

```
<input
    name="name"
    type="text"
    ng-model="model.software.name"
    required>
<div ng-messages="myForm.myInput.$error" ng-if="myForm.name.$touched && myForm.name.$invalid">
    <p ng-message="required">Required warning</p>
</div>

<input
    name="myInput"
    type="text"
    ng-model="myInput"
    ng-pattern="/someregex/"
    async-validator>
<div ng-if="myForm.myInput.$pending">PENDING</div>
<div ng-messages="myForm.myInput.$error" ng-if="myForm.myInput.$touched && myForm.myInput.$invalid">
    <p ng-message="pattern">Pattern warning</p>
    <p ng-message="asyncValidator">async warning</p>
</div>

<button ng-click="process()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Process</button>
```

And here is my validator:

```
app.directive('asyncValidator', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.asyncValidator = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return $http.post('path', {value : viewValue}).then(
                    function (response) {
                        if (not_good) {
                            return $q.reject(not_good);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your async validator. Does it allow empty values to pass?

Comment: Thanks Anid, I've updated my question and added my validator. I am not sure what you mean by allowing empty values to pass.

By the way, the validator runs once when the page loads, also not sure why.

Thanks again

Comment: is your server saying the blank value is good or not_good?

Comment: I've not worked with asyncValidators before. Just wondering if it is supposed to run its function when the input is null.

Comment: you might be right - if you aren't interacting with the field, that validator is probably not fired. What is your `regexp`? - aka - something is marking that field as invalid - either the asyncValidator or the ng-pattern need to allow for an empty value. My money is on the regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging I found that it was my asyncvalidator that was not allowing blank values. This works, but if there is better way please let me know.

Thanks Anid and to everyone.

The adjusted validator:

```
app.directive('asyncValidator', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.asyncValidator = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ngModel.$isEmpty(viewValue)) {
                    return $q.resolve();
                }
                return $http.post('path', {value : viewValue}).then(
                    function (response) {
                        if (not_good) {
                            return $q.reject(not_good);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```